# Low capacity on UPS model Hantol HU1000 for PC

Tags: power-supply, power, ups

How should one care about UPS (do maintenance of UPS) for a home computer?

I am asking because after one case where UPS was discharged fully (till it was empty), it now does not hold the power: it provides power from battery only for about a few minutes, and it doesn't give 'low battery' warning as it used to.

The UPS in question is Hantol HU1000, and the user's guide consist of 4 page leaflet in Engrish.  It is written there "charge the mattery every 3 months regularly" (which I didn't do), but does not explain how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only have to charge your mattery if the UPS is left powered off, it should automatically trickle charge it continuously while it is running. None of the UPS in this building require any service other than checking the front panel and a quick clean of the air filters. I don't know about your model but mine gives a minimum figure for mattery life (if maintained in the right conditions) of 5 years. One small UPS in a lecture room here has been running for over 6 years now with no repairs or replacements at all.